# Remove data from a cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

I want to remove data from multiple cells in a spreadsheet using Excel 2010, so I only have the email address left.

They are in the current format:

**M: 04545 545 545 e: test@email.com h: 01187 475 454**

Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Assumption:**

You don't have space in any of email id(I doubt you will.)

**Solution:**

Use a feature called **text to columns** in **data** tab excel(2007/10).

Use "Space" as custom delimiter.(It is pretty self-explanatory and shows you a preview as well).

That will get all the email addresses in single call and rest of the data in other columns. Then just delete the un-needed columns...

Answer (score 2):

If its a one off, just use Find/Replace in two steps

Replace `M:* e:`   with nothing (note the space on the end)
Replace  `h: *` with nothing (note the leading space)

Answer (score 1):

**Assumptions**

- The A column contains the data (otherwise change the references in the below formula)
- All cells in question contain the text `e:` before and `h:` after the e-mail

**Strategy**

- In a new column, create a formula that extracts the e-mail
- If warranted, copy/paste the new column using Paste Values and remove the original columns

**Formula**

```
=MID(A1;FIND("e: ";A1)+3;FIND("h: ";A1)-FIND("e: ";A1)-4
```

`MID` retrieves a substring of the original cell using a start index and a specified number of characters. `FIND` is used to get the index of the `e:` and `h:` markers.